# Xcode / C errors: Expected expression, Missing terminating '"' character

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm incredibly new to C and Xcode in general. Could somebody explain why this isn't working, and how to fix it?

[image: puu.sh/bVxTM/cfcb8d40b4.png]

Comment: The error is on this line: `message:@The star is circumpolar!"`

Comment: In the future, please copy and paste the offending code into the question rather than posting a link to a screenshot of your IDE.  I realize you were trying to show the code together with the errors messages, but we can't rely on external sites and we want to be able to copy the code onto our own machines and test it for ourselves.

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for further advice along those lines.

Comment: Oh, your *other* problem is that you're using C++-style casts in Objective C: `int(whatever)` needs to be `(int)(whatever)` or, in this case, probably just `whatever` without the casts at all.

Answer (score 1):

You have a number of issues.

Regarding the `Expected Expression` error, you declared `_declination` and `_latitude` as `UITextField`. To get the integer value, you can use: `_declination.text.intValue`. In context:

```
if (_declination.text.intValue >= 90 - _latitude.text.intValue)
```

Regarding `Missing terminating character "` you need to change:

```
@The star is circumpolar"
```

to:

```
@"The star is circumpolar"
```

Comment: Thanks, that's sorted out some of the errors. It's still giving some though, but I can't post it here because of the character limit. Edit: This line is giving the Missing terminating character error, even though it's there; the first set of speech marks after message are highlighted.                              message:@"Oops, something went wrong.”

Comment: @SamCartwright Please update your question by pasting your updated code with the line that produces the error.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a quote:

"The star is circumpolar!"